# Unity Android Application "Unable to load native library" and "Failed to mkdirat" Project Tango

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, project, google-project-tango, tango

I have been having issues with an application I am developing on Unity, so to make sure that it wasn't a problem with any of my work I started a new project and only installed the Tango plugin. After following the instructions to create a basic application and run it on my device the application still crashes on start up. Any help is appreciated!

```
I/ActivityManager(  898): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.test.test cmp=com.test.test/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity} from pid 4198

W/art     (  164): Could not get current activity

I/ActivityManager(  898): Start proc com.test.test for activity com.test.test/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity: pid=4691 uid=10073 gids={50073, 3003, 1028, 1015}

W/FlurryAgent( 4382): Flurry session paused for context:com.mobisystems.files.FileBrowser@64adfb28

E/cutils  (  156): Failed to mkdirat(/storage/sdcard1/Android): Read-only file system

W/Vold    (  156): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30

W/ContextImpl( 4691): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/obb/com.test.test

E/cutils  (  156): Failed to mkdirat(/storage/sdcard1/Android): Read-only file system

W/Vold    (  156): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30

W/ContextImpl( 4691): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.test.test/files

W/NativeActivity( 4691): ANativeActivity_onCreate not found

D/AndroidRuntime( 4691): Shutting down VM

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691): Process: com.test.test, PID: 4691

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.test.test-1/libmain.so

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2196)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.test.test-1/libmain.so

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:186)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity.onCreate(GoogleUnityActivity.java:44)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2160)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4691):    ... 9 more

W/ActivityManager(  898):   Force finishing activity com.test.test/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity

I/art     (  898): Heap trim of managed (duration=14.793833ms, advised=2MB) and native (duration=3.858334ms, advised=556KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 65%.
```

Comment: What Unity version are you running?

Comment: I have tried it using Unity 5.4.0 and 5.3.5

Comment: Unity 5.4.0.... what B version? Just 5.4.0? B1 B2...?

Comment: It was using Unity Version 5.4.0b19

Comment: You are out of luck. This problem was supposedly fixed in version 5.4.0b8 https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/blank-unity-project-crashes-at-start-on-specific-android-devices-from-unity-5-dot-4  You should file for bug report. Start a new project without the tango plugin and see if it still crashes...

Comment: A blank project works just fine, but adding in the Tango plugin causes the same crash

Comment: Ok. This means that the the plugin is likely the problem. Are you running this on Tango device or just an Android device? Also, what is your **Minimum API Level** set to in Unity. Finally, Check your Android SDK let me know which version you installed. All these actually matter.

Comment: Tango. Minimum is set to 17. It looks like I have only installed sdk 23, I am currently installing 17.

Comment: Yeah. Install 17 as recommended

Comment: Installin SDK has not caused it to work, I am currently installing sdk levels 18 - 23 hoping the issue will resolve itself.

Comment: Hi Brandon, this is Jason from Tango team, have you resolved this issue? Internally, we have been using 5.1.1, and I tested with the version you are using, I don't see this issue with those version either.

Comment: Nope, I've even tried it using unity on another computer. Others have been having this issue as well.

Comment: I've got the same issue, Unity 5.4.0f1 and Qianru. My toolchain is up to date (Java 8.092, Android Studio 2.1 with latest SDK). I believe that the read-only filesystem errors are not an issue, as I see those on a build that does work (built with Unity 5.3.5).

Comment: @JasonGuo Since you work for Google, please share this problem with your team. Also try to fix it. There are many tango bug out there that are not being fixed. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38974215/3785314) is the-same problem which is a sign that this problem is not yet fixed.