# Unity 5.4.0f3 + Tango Project Tania Borealis 1.41 :Unable to start activity ComponentInfo com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

When i'm trying to "build and run" in Unity 5.4.0f3 with SDK Tango Project Tania Borealis 1.41. Tango's example project at least the project loaded to device (Tango dev kit) it falls at the start moment.

This problem represented at each Tango's Unity example from their github repo https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity

Does anybody solve this problem?

adb logcat:

```
W/NativeActivity(11902): ANativeActivity_onCreate not found

D/AndroidRuntime(11902): Shutting down VM

E/AndroidRuntime(11902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(11902): Process: com.projecttango.videodemo, PID: 11902

E/AndroidRuntime(11902): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projecttango.videodemo/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.projecttango.videodemo-1/libmain.so

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2196)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.projecttango.videodemo-1/libmain.so

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:186)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity.onCreate(GoogleUnityActivity.java:44)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2160)

E/AndroidRuntime(11902):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: The-same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37822590/3785314) No solution yet!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed by downgrade Unity3d to version 5.3.2f1 !!! Only in this revision it works